# Deciding whether a function is O(n), Ω(n), or Θ(n)

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

First of all, this is my homework question, i have my answers and i want to be sure whether i am missing something. I have difficulties about deciding whether f(n) is O(g(n)), Ω(g(n)), or Θ(g(n)):

a) f(n)= n<sup>0,1234</sup>, g(n)= n<sup>0,1233</sup>. I believe, here f(n) is Θ(g(n)) since g(n)

b) f(n)= 4<sup>n</sup>, g(n)= 5<sup>n</sup>. I think here f(n) = O(g(n)) since 5<sup>n</sup> always dominates

c) f(n)=n + log(log<sup>2</sup>n), g(n)=100n + (log(n))<sup>2</sup>. Here i think f(n) is Θ(g(n)) because normally, g(n) dominates but 10000f(n) dominates g(n), for example.

d) f(n)=3n(log(n!)) + n<sup>2</sup>, g(n)=n<sup>2</sup>log(log(n)). It looks to me that f(n) is O(g(n)) since g(n) always dominates

e)f(n)= f(n)+O(f(n)), g(n)= Θ(f(n)). Here i think f(n) is Θ(g(n)).

Am i right in my answers? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my format? @ZevChonoles

Comment: No; in fact, you did a better job than most new users who post here without using LaTeX. It's a bit easier to read LaTeX, because it's more clearly separated from the rest of the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take for example d): $ \log n! =\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log k \approx \int_{1}^{n} \log x dx = n \log n$. Hence $f(n) = 3 n^2  \log n + n^2  < 3 n^2 \log n +3 n^2  = 3n^2 ( 
\log n +1) \leq 6 n^2 \log n = O(n^2 \log n)$. Hence $f(n)=O(n^2 \log n)$. Now take the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ which clearly tends to infinity. Hence $f(n) = \omega((f(n))$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$, by definition $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$ and $f(n) = O(g(n))$. Think of $\Omega$ as a lower bound, $O$ as an upper bound, while $\Theta$ is somewhat like "equal to".